# Batch How to extract multiple zip files to their origin folder with 7zip?

Tags: batch-file, zip, 7zip

I have multiple zip files in different folders and want to extract them into the folder they are in.

```
Parent Folder
    -Folderwithzip1
        --zip1
        --[Content from zip1 should land here]
    -Folderwithzip2
        --zip2
        --[Content from zip2 should land here]
```

I've tried

```
for /r "C:\zip" %f in (*.zip) do do 7z x -o "%~dpf" "%f"
```

I also tried

```
FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%F IN (`DIR /b *.zip`) DO ("C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e "%%F" -y)
```

but that does only extract the files in the folder where the batch file sits.

But the batch does not even start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line contains twice the keyword `do` which is the first mistake.

The second mistake is the space character between `-o` and `"%~dpf"`.

The help of **7-Zip** is the file `7zip.chm` in program files folder of **7-Zip** which can be either opened from within **7-Zip** or by double clicking on this file. There is on tab **Contents** the list item **Command Line Version** with the sublist item **Switches** containing the link to **-o (set Output directory) switch**. The syntax explained on this help page as well as the examples don't have a space between switch `-o` and directory path.

**7-Zip** also outputs an appropriate error message on execution with a space between `-o` and the output directory path:

> Command Line Error:
>   Too short switch:
>   -o

So the solution is quite simple for the command line usage:

```
for /R "C:\zip" %I in (*.zip) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -o"%~dpI" -y -- "%I"
```

And for usage in a batch file with each percent sign escaped with one more percent sign:

```
for /R "C:\zip" %%I in (*.zip) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -o"%%~dpI" -y -- "%%I"
```

I suggest also running in a command prompt window `for /?` and read the help output for command **FOR**.

**DIR** is not needed here except there are also *.zip files with hidden attribute set which are always ignored by **FOR** or some of the ZIP files contain itself *.zip files and extracting those *.zip files should be avoided on running the batch file. Run in a command prompt window `dir /?` for help on command **DIR**.

The following command line can be used in a batch file to first run the command **DIR** in a separate command process started by **FOR** with using `cmd /C`, capture everything written by **DIR** to handle **STDOUT** and then process all captured lines (= full qualified file names) line by line:

```
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "C:\zip\*.zip" /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -o"%%~dpI" -y -- "%%I"
```

**DIR** option `/S` is required here to let **DIR** search also in all subdirectories of `C:\zip` for *.zip files and get output the name of the found *.zip files with full path instead of file name only.